# My Employer wants me to attend staff meetings after work

Tags: meetings, education, discrimination, employment

I am a teacher who has been working for the same employer for over 15 years. My employer recently decided to require that I attend staff meetings twice each month after regular working hours. However, I am taking my final classes for a degree which will lead to a pay raise and possibly a future promotion. I am required me to attend the evening university classes twice each week, which I have been doing for the last two years

This recent decision from my employer has put me into a stressful situation and I believe it's unfair. As they argue, the meetings are mandatory that they are listed on my collective agreement; however, I am unable to find those terms in the agreement.

I am doing this degree mainly for personal and professional development. It is work related even though I pay for it myself.

Please advise me on this situation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is likely to be closed as either a company-specific policy or a legal question.  Have you approached your boss or your HR department about this?  If you can't get anywhere there, then you may have to speak with a lawyer, or possibly a union representative if you have a union.  Lastly, we don't know what country you are in and the laws are normally company specific.

Comment: @Sarah: Welcome to the site; hopefully youl'll find it helpful I edited your post to fix some grammar issues and make it more readable (perhaps that will stop the close votes too).  If I've changed what you were trying to say, please feel free to [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/54938/edit) the post yourself; once on the edit page, you can rollback to a previous version if you want, or just modify what I've done.

Comment: You can't attend staff meetings "after work". If you attend a staff meeting then it _is work_. So you are not asked to attend staff meetings after work, you are asked to work additional hours, outside your normal contractual hours, and likely without pay.

Comment: If you have a collective agreement, you should consult with your union representative, or whatever the equivalent is. They will have the answer, or they can point you to who will have the answer.

Comment: As Jane recommended, if you are part of a union certainly talk to them. They will know what your employer is and is not allowed to do.

Answer (score 11):

You have two options to resolve this easily which I would try in this order:

Option one, talk to your boss and explain about your University commitments, ideally he/she will understand, but if they do insist there is option 2, which in my experience will always work.

Option 2, go and talk to whoever is heading the University course and explain to them that you have work commitments that cannot be changed. This person will be able to find a way for you to either attend other classes at different times, or exempt you from attending classes if you do the coursework another way and hand in your work.

Both options have a high chance of resolving your problem. Universities will bend over backwards to accommodate adult students who are working full time. It's in their best interests to do so.

Hope that helps

Comment: To add, if your (final) exams falls on the meeting dates, most universities will allow for accommodations. Also I been in classes where I could email homework in while I was oversea for a family death. Since I could not match the timezone, I told the professor I wasn't sure when I would email it other than I would on the date it was due +/- a day. He was very accepting of it and understood my situation. You just have to be forward about it prior to the date so things can be set up for you.